# Random variable associated with a function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading Rick Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples ($5^{\text{th}}$ Edition) and the author states the following Theorem (Theorem $1.2.2$):

If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0, \infty)$ satisfies the following:

$(i)$ $F$ is non-decreasing

$(ii)$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x) =1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F(x) =0$

$(iii)$ $F$ is right-continuous i.e. $\lim_{y\downarrow x}F(y) = F(x)$

then $F$ is the distribution function of some random variable.

To prove the theorem, the author defines $\Omega = (0, 1)$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(0,1)$ and $P = \text{Lesbegue measure}$. The author then claims that $X(\omega):=\sup\{y\in \mathbb{R}:F(y)<\omega\}$ is the desired random variable.

**Question:** How does one prove that $X$ is measurable (this is not explicitly proved in the book)?

**Thoughts:** The author proves that 
$$X^{-1}((-\infty, x]) = \{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\leq x\} = \{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\leq F(x)\} = (-\infty, F(x)]\cap(0, 1)$$ 
From here one could claim that $X^{-1}(\sigma\{(-\infty, x]: x\in\mathbb{R}\}) = X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) = \sigma(\{(-\infty, F(x)]\cap(0,1): x\in\mathbb{R}\})$

But is it possible to prove that this $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathcal{B}(0,1)$?

Comment: You don’t need it to equal $\cal{B}(0,1)$. In general it may not be. You only need it to be contained in $\cal{B}(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense and is also trivial to prove.

Comment: No problem. Please consider writing an answer (and accepting it) to your own question so that this question is removed from the unanswered category. It might also be helpful to other users who have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments it is sufficient to prove that $\sigma(\{(-\infty, F(x)]\cap(0, 1):x\in\mathbb{R}\})\subseteq \mathcal{B}(0, 1)$. If $F(x)<1$ then clearly $(-\infty, F(x)]\cap(0, 1) = (0, F(x)]\in\mathcal{B}(0, 1)$ and if $F(x) = 1$ then again $(-\infty, F(x)]\cap(0, 1) = (0, 1)\in\mathcal{B}(0, 1)$. So $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $(-\infty, F(x)]\cap(0, 1)\in\mathcal{B}(0, 1)$ and therefore the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X$ is a non-decreasing function. For any non-decreasing function $f$ observe that $\{x: f (x) <a\}$ is an interval for any real number $a$. Hence $X$ is measurable.